# Tools/R code for predicting Dragon-Kings

Tags: r, prediction, software

The theory of the so called Dragon-Kings, esp. by Didier Sornette (ETH Zürich), basically states that financial crises and crashes are predictable (contrary to the [theory of black swans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory)).

The following paper gives an overview (see esp. section 5, p. 20f. for predictability):
[Dragon-Kings: Mechanisms, Statistical Methods and Empirical Evidence by Didier Sornette, Guy Ouillon](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2191590)

**My question**
Do you know any software, tools, Excel sheets and/or preferably R code/packages with which the predictability of Dragon-Kings can be tested?

Comment: +1 just for linking to paper with most statistically improbable phrase of the week, namely "Dragon-kings due to unsustainable transient herding in grand canonical minority games".

Comment: I flipped through the paper and found it to be utter "humbug". Nowhere have the authors established nor presented a statistical study that would support that there is any reliable way to forecast extreme events. While I disagree with Taleb in many ways I would say he is spot on in claiming black swans cannot be predicted but only subsequently managed. No earthquake (as of today) can be reliably predicted nor a financial crisis. For each guy who claimed he pinpointed the day the market put in a top there are 20 guys who did so before and got burned. But of course one should never stop dreaming

Comment: @MattWolf: Yes and no: In general I am with you in being überskeptical yet this guy from ETH Zürich (!) regularly publishes encrypted forecasts of crashes on Arxiv and decryptes them to proof that his method works. See e.g. his TED talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_eFjLZqXt8 - there are also many Google references to be found.

Comment: @vonjd, what do you mean with "encrypted forecasts" and why you encrypt something, archive it and then decrypt it? I am not falling victim to a catch-the-fool type of post right now, am I? ;-) (I generally highly value your posts and read them with much interest but you have be gotten completely lost here).

Comment: By the way, I did watch the TED speech and felt it was a waste of time, why: All his reasons of why he can predict extreme events are accurate, however, the exact same variable states occur in countless market observations that do not lead to extreme events (increasing autocorrelation, increasing variance, increases in cross-correlations with external factors...). So, it again comes down to the same guy screaming "extreme event ahead" who screamed 20 times before and was proven incorrect. I did not come across his name forecasting any past extreme events. How come?

Comment: He encrypts it because people accused him of being the reason markets fell after he published the forecast (= self fulfilling prophecy). And I don't believe it at face value either - this is why I want to conduct experiments of my own and this is why I posted the question in the first place. I am a permasceptic like you are!

Comment: Sornette has a book [Why Stock Markets Crash: Critical Events in Complex Financial Systems](http://www.amazon.com/Why-Stock-Markets-Crash-Financial/dp/0691118507/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1373980797&sr=1-1).  I've largely stood with Taleb's thinking on this for sometime, but looking at things like multi-fractals has begun to make me reconsider whether we may develop the ability to do this.  (Taleb claims to have collaborated a with Mandelbrot in his last years to try to do some of this).  Sornette seems like a sincere guy, just not convinced he's nailed it yet.

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you at least give a hint why you downvoted? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite tool is Sornette's own Finanical Crisis Observatory: http://tasmania.ethz.ch/pubfco/fco.html

If you are interested, I have developed my own tool in Java and JavaCL which can be found here: https://thebubbleindex.codeplex.com/

Update: Code moved to github: https://github.com/thebubbleindex/thebubbleindex

Comment: A very warm welcome to Quant.SE and thank you for your interesting answer!

Comment: codeplex.com is going to be shut down by the end of 2017. You may consider moving your code to github.com or elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python package that calibrates the model: https://github.com/Boulder-Investment-Technologies/lppls